# Why is my Ansible Playbook listing the name of every file in the directory?

Tags: bash, shell, ansible

I am having an issue with my Ansible playbook printing every file in the directory that the `.yml` file is in. This only happens when I run it in a bash script.

So say that I had

```
 /MY_ANSIBLE
  dumbPlaybook.yml
  some_other_file1.txt
  some_other_file2.txt
  some_other_file3.txt
  some_other_file4.txt
```

Shell script that calls my playbook and looks for errors. I want to do this:

```bash
do_stuff_res=`doStuff`
echo $do_stuff_res
```

because that way I can execute the command AND see the output from the level of my bash script. (one which runs a bunch of playbooks)

```bash
doStuff () {
    cd /web/MY_ANSIBLE/ansible/
    # If I run this line alone I DO NOT see the printout of all the files
    /home/MY_ANSIBLE/.local/bin/ansible-playbook dumbPlaybook.yml
    cd -
}

do_stuff_res=`doStuff`
echo $do_stuff_res
if echo $do_stuff_res | grep -q 'failed=1'; then
  echo "Failed!!!"
  exit 1
fi
```

The playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: RANDOM DEBUG
      debug: 
        msg: "Foo"
```

If I call that shell script, I get this output:

```
/home/MY_ANSIBLE/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible/parsing/vault/__init__.py:44: CryptographyDeprecationWarning: Python 3.6 is no longer supported by the Python core team. Therefore, support for it is deprecated in cryptography and will be removed in a future release.
  from cryptography.exceptions import InvalidSignature
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/paramiko/transport.py:236: CryptographyDeprecationWarning: Blowfish has been deprecated
  "class": algorithms.Blowfish,
[WARNING]: Invalid characters were found in group names but not replaced, use
-vvvv to see details
Using /web/MY_ANSIBLE/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file PLAY [localhost] 

[[ ... here it will print a HUGE list of EVERY single file in the directory of my playbook ... ]]

dumbPlaybook.yml some_other_file1.txt some_other_file2.txt some_other_file3.txt some_other_file4.txt

127.0.0.1 : ok=2 changed=0 unreachable=0 failed=0 skipped=0 rescued=0 ignored=0 /web/MY_ANSIBLE/ansible
```

`ansible.cfg`, in case that's relevant:

```
[defaults]
inventory = inventory/ansible.host
host_key_checking=False
deprecation_warnings=False
timeout = 120
verbosity = 1
```

This becomes incredibly tedious to read as there are many playbooks that ALL do this.

Comment: I have copied your script and run it and get the expected output `TASK [RANDOM DEBUG]
 foo main.yml script.sh Thursday 27 October 2022 19:30:43 +0100 (0:00:00.997) 0:00:01.018 foo main.yml script.sh ok: [localhost] => { "msg": "Foo" }`

Comment: `echo $do_stuff_res` -- quote your variables.

Comment: For future reference for anyone it may help, this solved my problem:

```shell
#!/bin/bash
doStuff () {
    cd /web/cquant/ansible/
    /home/cquant/.local/bin/ansible-playbook dumbPlaybook.yml --extra-vars "domain_name=devtest.cquant.io" 2>&1 | tee blah.txt
    cd -
}

doStuff
do_stuff_res=`cat blah.txt`
if echo $do_stuff_res | grep -q 'failed=1'; then
  echo "Failed!!!"
  exit 1
fi
```